# What is correct implementation of IDA* algorithm with manhattan heuristic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, puzzle, heuristics

I am trying to implement IDA* algorithm to solve 15 puzzle problem in objective C, I have implemented the algorithm very well but not getting the exact result. Here is my code-

```
- (TreeNode *)IDAStarSolution:(TreeNode *)startState {
int limit = 5;//2*[startState fx];

appDelegate.CN=[NSNumber numberWithInt:limit];

TreeNode *result=nil;

while (result==nil) {
    [appDelegate.closedList addObject:startState];
    newLimit = 99999;
    result = [self depthLimitSearch:startState costLimit:limit];
    limit = newLimit;
    appDelegate.CN=[NSNumber numberWithInt:newLimit];
    [appDelegate.closedList removeAllObjects];
}
return result;
}

- (TreeNode*)depthLimitSearch:(TreeNode *)current costLimit:(int)currentCostBound {
NSArray *neighbors =[current expandNodeToChilds];
for (TreeNode *s in neighbors) {
    if ([s.puzzleBox isFinalStateBox]) {
        appDelegate.result=s.moveString;
        return s;
    }

    if (![self closedSetContains:s]) {

        int currentCost = [s.cost intValue] + [s.puzzleBox.manhattanDistance intValue];
        if (currentCost <= currentCostBound) {
            [appDelegate.closedList addObject:s];
            [s.puzzleBox displayPuzzleBox];

            TreeNode *solution = [self depthLimitSearch:s costLimit:currentCostBound];
            if (solution!=nil&& (bestSolution ==nil|| [solution.cost intValue] < [bestSolution.cost intValue])) {
                bestSolution = solution;
                //return solution;
            }
        }else {
            if (currentCost < newLimit) {
                NSLog(@"new limit %d", currentCost);
                newLimit = currentCost;
            }
        }
    }
}
return bestSolution;
}


-(BOOL)closedSetContains:(TreeNode *)node{
for (TreeNode *tNode in appDelegate.closedList) {
    if (tNode==node) {
        return YES;
    }
}
return NO;
}
```

The depthLimitedSearch always returning null, and then expand the same node again and again.
So what i have done wrong please suggest.

Implementation is similar to java code given at : 
[Iterative Deepening A Star (IDA*) to solve n-puzzle (sliding puzzle) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033252/iterative-deepening-a-star-ida-to-solve-n-puzzle-sliding-puzzle-in-java)

As i am returning bestSolution now, if i set the limit more than optimum cost then it returns the first solution it found, which is not optimum. What to do now?

Comment: The final return from your depthLimitSearch is nil, so as you back out of your recursion you are always going to get nil. Your other return is commented

Comment: That is commented because i am not utilising that one, i replaced return nil to return bestSolution.  Is this okay according to IDA* algorithm?

Comment: That should help. The way it was unless your solution was found immediately you would get nil

Comment: Now getting an error as <__NSArrayM: 0x8c38820> was mutated while being enumerated.' .  I think it is for neighbours, but why?

Comment: As i am returning bestSolution now, if i set the limit more than optimum cost then it returns the first solution it found, which is not optimum. What to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mutation/enumeration problem is caused by the structure of your `closedSetContains` method.  You are enumerating `appDelegate.closedList` but return from the middle of the enumeration.   I suspect that when you then modify `appDelegate.closedList` it causes the error, because it looks like the enumeration is still active.  You should be able to confirm this by checking the array reference from the exception with the array `appDelegate.closedList` in the debugger.

Changing your `closedSetContains` to this -

```
-(BOOL)closedSetContains:(TreeNode *)node{
  BOOL ret=NO;
  for (TreeNode *tNode in appDelegate.closedList) {
    if (tNode==node) {
      ret=YES;
      break;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

may help.  But if `appDelegate.closedList` is an NSMutableArray you can replace the whole method with    `[appDelegate.closedList containsObject:node]`

Comment: Thanks, it's the simplest way.